# Database Sql Chain Integers in row

Tags: sql, database, string, integer

At the moment I have for each users an integer in my database

which datatype would I have to use if I want to chain multiply integers for a single users in my database?

Now:

```
__________________________________
Users                   Numbers
Tom                     2
__________________________________
```

What I want:

```
__________________________________
Users                   Numbers
Tom                     2,12
__________________________________
```

Comment: Separate rows is a better idea. Comma separated values is a mess in the dbms world, will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

As @jarlh stated, you shouldn't design your database to contain a set of data.

A relational database column must contain only a data of a single kind and not a set of data or different kinds of data through your rows.

To fix your error you can create another table named `Numbers` and associate it to your `Users` table with a ***1:N** (one to many) relation* like shown here:

```
 _Users___      _Numbers________________
|ID |name |    |NumberID |UserID |value |
|1  |Tom  |    |1        |3      |243   |
|2  |Jess |    |2        |1      |12    |
|3  |Luis |    |3        |2      |87    |
```

In the `Users` table you have an `ID` and the `name`, then in your `Numbers` table you associate **a number** *(for each new number you must insert a new row)* to its owner with the foreign key `UserID`